# find_first_of with multiple characters doesn't return string::npos when substring shouldn't be present

Tags: c++, msys

I've written a small snippet like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s1{"abcdefghijklmnop"};

    std::cout << "s1(fg) = " << s1.find_first_of("fg") << '\n';
    std::cout << "s1(fo) = " << s1.find_first_of("fo") << '\n';
}
```

I expect that it returns 5 and string::npos, but it actually returns

```
s1(fg) = 5
s1(fo) = 5
```

Why does it work like this?

My compile flags and g++ version:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp

$ g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) returns the position of *any* of the characters you supply to it. In your case, it finds `f` both times.

You should be using [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't clear to me that it behaves in that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the API behaves:

> Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in str.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't clear to me that it behaves in that way.